# Search MongoDB to return all values for a parameter

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm running an app built with `Angular`, built on a `Node`/`Express`/`MongoDB` stack.

In my Mongo database, I have objects that look like this:

```
{
    "infoLink" : "http://foo.com",
    "name" : "Fossil Watch",
    "gender" : "mens",
    "price" : "$166.44",
    "store" : "Store Name",
    "designer" : "Fossil",
},
{
    "infoLink" : "http://foo.com",
    "name" : "Timex Watch",
    "gender" : "mens",
    "price" : "$166.44",
    "store" : "Store Name",
    "designer" : "Timex",
},
{
    "name" : "Casio Watch",
    "gender" : "mens",
    "price" : "$166.44",
    "store" : "Store Name",
    "designer" : "Casio",
}
```

I want to find a way to search `mongoDB` to find and list all of the elements from one parameter. For instance, I want to search through all entries and extract their "designer" value, so as to return:

`record = ['Fossil', 'Timex', 'Casio']`

In practice I have about 20,000 records that I'm searching through here, so I'd like it to be as speedy and efficient as possible.

Is there a way to do this without resorting to getting all records then looping through each to find the desired parameter and adding it to an array? That solution would be like this:

```
var arr=[];
db.products.find(criteria, function (err, record) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Lookup Error: " + err);
        } else{
            record.forEach(function(data){
              if (arr.indexOf(data.designer) > -1){
                  arr.push(data.designer);
               }
            });
        }
    });
```

but I feel like this is a pretty clunky way to do it. Any better options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a distinct query:

```
db.products.distinct("designer")
```

[db.collection.distinct()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for, works perfectly. Don't know why that other answer was talking about.